# maxvid_decode.h in ios project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm building an iOS project in Xcode and getting the following error, screenshot attached.

How do I remove this error please?

Parse issue, expected ')'

[image]

Comment: Sometimes Xcode gets a little bonkers when you try to import any objective c into a c file.  Is that what's happening?

Comment: The bulk of my code is objective c.  Presumably the code above is C?  How do I resolve?

Comment: that's not what I asked.  What does the file look like (or at least the header imports), because occasionally this kind of thing occurs with weird header imports.